# Proof or Counterexample for Integral of Function that Goes to Zero Faster than 1/x

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

Suppose we have a function $f(x)$ that goes to zero faster than $1/x$. That is,

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} xf(x) = 0.
$$

I was wondering, does it then follow that the improper integral

$$
\int_1^{\infty} f(x)\, dx
$$

converges, assuming that $f$ is continuous and finite on the interval $[1, \infty)$. If not, can you provide a counterexample?

Comment: I believe $\frac{1}{x*\ln(x)}$ diverges, but it reaches zero faster than $1/x$.

Comment: Sweet, thanks!!

Comment: For any monotonic $g:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb R^+$ such that  $\int_1^{\infty} g(x)dx$ diverges there is a monotonic $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb R^+$ such that $\int_1^{\infty}f(x)dx$ diverges and $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)/g(x)=0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments,
$$ \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x \ln x} dx = \infty.$$
You might then ask *what if $f(x) x \ln x \to 0$, does that mean that $\int_1^\infty f dx$ converges?*
And the answer is no! In fact,
$$ \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x \ln x \ln \ln x} dx = \infty$$
as well. And generally,
$$ \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x \ln x (\ln \ln x) \cdots (\underbrace{\ln \cdots \ln x}_{\text{n many}})} dx = \infty.$$

Comment: To the O.P.:  For each of these examples you have a function $f(x)$ that is decreasing and positive  for all sufficiently large $x$. So $0<f(n+1)<\int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx$ for all sufficiently large $ n.$ And the divergence of $\sum_nf(n+1)$ can be easily shown by repeated application of the Cauchy Condensation Test....